# Meteor dynamic non-collection forms

Tags: javascript, meteor, file-structure

I have started learning MeteorJS and I have some problems with the structure of the project. I am trying to create a quiz app without saving answers to database, but showing them in a summary page after the completion of the quiz. I have tried to make something similar to [this](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#non-collection-forms) but I am getting some errors. This is my structure of the project:

```
\client
    \questions
        events.js
        helpers.js
        \templates
            ...
    \shared
        ...
\common
    schema.js
\lib
    router.js
    style.less
    \bootstrap
        ...
    \controllers
        base.js
        main_page.js
        single_question.js
    \methods
        questions.js
\public
    ...
\server
    publications.js
```

I have been trying to get schema from common/schema.js:

```
quizSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    question: {
        type: String,
        autoform: {
            type: "select-radio",
            options: function() {
                return [{
                    label: "Yes",
                    value: 1
                }, {
                    label: "No",
                    value: 0
                }];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In client/questions/helpers.js like so:

```
var quizForm = new AutoForm(quizSchema);
Template.newQuestion.helpers({
    questionForm: function() {
        return quizForm;
    }
});
```

but I get **undefined quizSchema**. If I define quizSchema inside the helpers.js then I get **autoForm is not a function**. I have all the required packages. So my questions would be:

1. What would be the correct structure of this project to fix the problem above?
2. How could I override question schema after going to the next question? I am thinking in client/questions/events.js, but I do not know if it will override the schema.
3. What is the best way to review quiz answers in a summary page? The data should disappear after refresh of the whole page.